# Cannot bind parameter ´Replace´ to the target

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I tried to copy AD attributes for each user in a specific OU with the following command:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=My,OU=OUnit,DC=Domain,DC=local" -Filter * -Properties extensionAttribute14, physicalDeliveryOfficeName |
    Set-ADUser -Replace @{street=$($_.extensionAttribute14);l=$($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -replace '^\d+\s+');postalCode=$($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -replace '[a-zA-Z\s]+')}
```

But then I get this error message:

> Set-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Replace' to the target. Exception setting "Replace": "Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object."

I also tried to pipe it to:

```
ForEach-Object {Set-ADObject -Identity $_.DistinguishedName -Replace @{...}}
```

But I also receive the same error message there.

Comment: there is no attribute named "street", try with "streetAddress" instead that might fix it

Comment: We have a attribute called "street". The command also works, if I put the ```-Filter```  to one user only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your comment i tried it out myself and was able to replicate the problem. (But other than you describe it doesn´t work for a single user either).

This is was worked for me for one and multiple users:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=My,OU=OUnit,DC=Domain,DC=local" -Filter * -Properties extensionAttribute14, physicalDeliveryOfficeName | % {
Set-ADUser $_ -Replace @{street=$($_.extensionAttribute14);l=$($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -replace '^\d+\s+');postalCode=$($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -replace '[a-zA-Z\s]+')} }
```